# Check columns for groups of strings, replace with 1 if they exist 0 if they do not - python, pandas, logical operators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, logical-operators

I'm trying to search for a set of strings in a column in a pandas dataframe and replace with 1 if the strings exist and 0 if they do not.

Per the example below, this works fine on the first pass:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4], 'Event':['1 Day', '2 Days','3 Days','4 Days']})
df['Event'] = np.where(df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days'),1,df['Event'])

df
```

but when I try and apply the opposite logic and replace the instances where the strings do not exist:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4], 'Event':['1 Day', '2 Days','3 Days','4 Days']})
df['Event'] = np.where(df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days'),1,df['Event'])
df['Event'] = np.where(~df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days'),0,df['Event'])  

df
```

I get this error - `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`

I tried using logical operators so the actions would occur simultaneously:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4], 'Event':['1 Day', '2 Days','3 Days','4 Days']})
df['Event'] = np.where(df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days'),1,df['Event']) & np.where(~df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days'),0,df['Event'])  

df
```

but received this error... `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'`

What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is a df that replaces all the cells where the strings exist with 1 and the instances where those strings do not exist with 0s so I can analyze. Like so:

```
ID  Event
1   0  
2   0
3   1
4   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line:

```
df['Event'] = np.where(df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days'),1, df['Event'])
```

`df['Event']` contains 1 which is not a string, so the second time you check (inside `np.where`):

```
df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days')
```

it returns:

```
0    False
1    False
2      NaN
3      NaN
Name: Event, dtype: object
```

Since NaN doesn't evaluate `~NaN`, it returns an error.

To get the desired outcome, simply use `np.where` once where you select 1 if True, 0 otherwise:

```
df['Event'] = np.where(df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days'), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
   ID  Event
0   1      0
1   2      0
2   3      1
3   4      1
```

Comment: Oh, that last entry is an "otherwise"... thank you!! Makes sense now I think about it, that's why I had to have the df["Col"] in there. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `True`/`False` is the same as `1`/`0`, you can simply use your conditional statement as your new data for `df['Event']`. `np.where` (or `df.loc` for that matter) is an unnecessary extra step in this case.

```
df['Event'] = df['Event'].str.contains('3 Days|4 Days').astype(int)

   ID  Event
0   1      0
1   2      0
2   3      1
3   4      1
```

Comment: This is also good, thanks. Though I like how explicit the first answer is, is also means I can assign different values if necessary.